# Conversion from string "M" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issues with conversion of values that I am trying to reference via a field that I want to format from an ERP System. I am unable to convert all of my values because they are being pulled out as strings, no matter if variables are set to integer or string. What am I doing that would cause this error, should variables be defined a different way?

```
Public Class Class1
Inherits erp.Rule
Public Overrides Function Execute() As erp.RuleResult 
Dim Result As New RuleResult
    Try
        Dim date_recieved As Date
        Dim month As String
        Dim period As String
        Dim Year1 As String
        Dim Year As String 
date_recieved = Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("date_received").FieldValue
        month = Format(date_recieved, "M").ToString
        Year = Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("yearAR").FieldValue
        period = Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("periodAR").FieldValue

        If period = month Then
            If Year = Year1 Then
                Exit Function
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Date received does not match year", "Invalid Input")
            End If

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Date received does not match period", "Invalid Input")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Result.Message = ex.Message
    End Try
    Result.Success = True
    Return Result
  End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

`Format` does not accept a string parameter, by you passing "M" it is trying to convert the datatype you supply to the datatype the function accepts and since a string does not implicitly cast to an integer an error occurs

To format a `Date` type to various formats of string you just use your date variable and its subsequent `.ToString()` method with your formatting rules as an argument of `.ToString()`

Here is a link to the msdn explaining all the possible formatting options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: In this case, how would I be able to format the date_recieved to just get the month, or is it not possible? I need to reference the period (month) to my month variable derived from date_received.

Comment: @ChristopherBachman Updated answer with an explanation and link to documentation for formatting :)